# Подключение к API Yclients. Python

Tags: python

Никак не получается подключиться к API сайта [Ycliets](https://yclients.com/).
Пытался использовать [внешнюю библиотеку](https://pypi.org/project/yclients-api/) но не смог в ней разобраться, возможно она не актуально уже для api сайта.

[Инструкция](https://support.yclients.com/67-68-199--dostup-k-api/)

[Документация API](https://developers.yclients.com/ru/)

Вот пример кода который я пытаюсь использовать:

```
import os

import requests
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

api_key = os.getenv('API_KEY_YCL')

headers = {
    'Authorization': f"Bearer {api_key}",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://api.yclients.com',
    headers=headers
    )

if response.status_code == 200:
    records = response.json()
    print(records)
else:
    print(f"Ошибка {response.status_code}: {response.text}")
```

Ответ:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Dev\integrations\yclients_api.py", line 21, in <module>
    records = response.json()
  File "C:\Dev\integrations\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Я начинающий разработчик, благодарю за помощь и ответы.